# App launched from the first screen from the foreground ios

Tags: iphone, ios, appdelegate

When I pressing "home" button, app calling `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`, ok its good, but when I wait for a some time (10-15 mins), app starting from first loading screen, why? I have added:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

But not success. I think it goes to suspended mode, how do I prevent this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It means that your app has been killed by the system.
You can't prevent it completely, the system kills background apps when it needs more memory, but you can do something like this:

- free as memory as you can when the app goes in background: doing this, when the system needs memory, your app won't be one of the first to be killed because its footprint is low.
- Since you can't be sure that your app won't be killed, use state preservation / restoration: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html)

EDIT:

since your app needs to reproduce audio in the background (as written in the comments) I give you some extra advices.

- remember to register your app background mode (from this link: [Multitasking guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)) --> "by including the UIBackgroundModes key (with the value audio) in its Info.plist file"
- the app continues to work in the background since it's playing audio, but when the audio is suspended the app is suspended too (it means that it can be killed). So, you must use state preservation to restore it when the user comes back.

Another extract:
"When the UIBackgroundModes key contains the audio value, the system’s media frameworks automatically prevent the corresponding app from being suspended when it moves to the background. As long as it is playing audio or video content, the app continues to run in the background. However, if the app stops playing the audio or video, the system suspends it."

Comment: I like the first bullet item, I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: yes, it is an option, but it doesn't guarantee that the app won't be killed :-( (and however, event if it's not killed, it is suspended, so  background work can be done only if the "additional background time" is requested, giving your app 10 minutes of non-increasable background time)

Answer (score 0):

You app has exited. If you want it to come back to where you left off you'll have to preserve the state somehow, check on launch, and then restore the state.

Comment: My app performing methods in background mode.. so it must working without relaunching.. =(

Comment: the things you can do in background are limited, so you'd better to read the ios multitasking guide to understand if what you want to do is possible: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

Comment: Ok, so the system shouldn't kill the app when it's playing audio, because this is an allowed background mode (have you declared it inside the .plist file?) :-) I assume that it kills the app only when the audio is paused, right? It this case, you must use state restoration to restore the state of the app as it was before the system killed it

Comment: App contains "Required background modes" and "App plays audio" value  in .plist. The problem is that I dont know when app must play audio when its going into background mode (it may be 1 min to 2 days).

Comment: I updated my answer. The app is alive in the background since the audio is playing. When the audio stops, it's suspended. At that time, you have to save the state (for example the audio track that the user is hearing, and the minute:seconds), so when the user comes back, f the app was previously killed, you can restore it. This is the only system :-)

Comment: I have a bad idea =) May I play some audio with audio player when app goes to background mode and after my main audio starts play my main sound I delete temp audio player. Is it possible?

Comment: possible, but if apple detects this you'll get rejected. I've seen this specifically called out as "illegal."